# How to plot loss from training log using Torch Framework

Tags: python, torch

I am training a lane detection model with Torch (not pytorch). The training script also creates a logfile which looks like this:

```
 | Epoch: [1][1/88880][1]  Time 4.91  LR 0.01000  Err1 0.09779 (0.09779)  Err2 0.03161 (0.03161)    
 | Epoch: [1][2/88880][2]  Time 1.51  LR 0.01000  Err1 0.16534 (0.13157)  Err2 0.03048 (0.03105)    
 | Epoch: [1][3/88880][3]  Time 1.57  LR 0.01000  Err1 0.33015 (0.19776)  Err2 0.15016 (0.07075)    
 | Epoch: [1][4/88880][4]  Time 1.49  LR 0.01000  Err1 0.12389 (0.17929)  Err2 0.03932 (0.06289)    
 | Epoch: [1][5/88880][5]  Time 1.49  LR 0.01000  Err1 0.13950 (0.17133)  Err2 0.03877 (0.05807)    
 | Epoch: [1][6/88880][6]  Time 1.49  LR 0.01000  Err1 0.26979 (0.18774)  Err2 0.03070 (0.05351)    
 | Epoch: [1][7/88880][7]  Time 1.52  LR 0.01000  Err1 0.41120 (0.21967)  Err2 0.04841 (0.05278)
```

Now I would like to plot the loss from every iteration. Is there a method in torch to plot the loss from the train log?

Also I have a second question. What is the difference between the first loss and the second loss in the brackets?

Answer (score 0):

1. The first question:

   - You may record the loss in each iteration, and the iteration index (1/88880 <- 1 is the iteration index).
   - Plot it using `matplotlib` package.

```py
indices = []
losses = []

for loop:
   losses.append(loss.item())
   indices.append(index)

# plot it
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(indices, losses)
```

2. The second question: 
   The first loss is the `loss` of first `batch` predictions, so it does for the second loss.